# Azure DevOps, how to make `ArtifactoryDotnetCore` fail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, artifactory

I have a pipeline that uses `ArtifactoryDotnetCore@1` for uploading a Nuget package to *Artifactory*. If a package was not found, the tasks succeeds, spitting out this into the log:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "totals": {
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 0
  }
}
```

The question is how to make it fail if "success" is 0.

I tried using an `arguments` input parameter, but it seems to only work with the `restore` command, not `push` that I am using.
I can't see anything useful in the *JFrog* documentation, and I can't see the source code.

I see possible solutions:

1. I missed some undocumented parameter, that can be used for the purpose
2. Using a different task, that can publish to Artifactory
3. Somehow retrieve and parse the output from the task (probably in the following task)
4. Manually build and call `jfrog.exe rt u ...` as a command line

Can somebody tell me whether (1), (2) or (3) can be achieved, or do I have to retreat to (4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the fail-no-op option, that fails the tasks if no files were uploaded.

That option is currently not available for the `Artifactory Dotnet Core` tasks (feel free to [open a feature request](https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-azure-devops-extension/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature%20request&template=feature_request.md&title=)).

A workaround would be using the `Artifactory Generic Upload` task. Behind the scenes both of these tasks run the `rt upload` command of JFrog CLI. On this task you can check the `"Fail task if no files were uploaded"` checkbox.

I don't think parsing the output is feasible.

For reference, note that the tasks mentioned here belong to the older extension, `Artifactory Azure DevOps Extension`. A new extension, `JFrog Azure DevOps Extension`, that uses JFrog CLI v2 is available. See info about the the new extension [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-WeCreatedaNewExtension).